# Get the version of another installed MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've seen many answers to variants of this question but couldn't find a working solution plus I fail to understand some related stuff, so:

I need to abort the installation (which I'm currently creating) if our old app is already installed.
The new MSI is user-scoped and the old one is machine-scoped, so I can use this for my advantage, plus an old version number can also indicate an old MSI.

I figured out (not so much to figure out actually) the conditional install.

Regarding the indication that the old MSI is installed - At first I searched for examples how to use ProductSearch, but then I've seen a SO comment stating it only works for bundles.
So I started searching how to registry search - but although I know *most* of the path where the old MSI is registring in (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall), I don't know the next subdir since it's the product code which according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productcode) should be autogenerated for every version etc.  It's also marked as * in our old wsx.

So how should I approach this? How should I search for the old MSI in the registry?
I can't scan the filesystem as the user may change the installation dir.
I prefer not to add another custom action though I will if I'll have no choice

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just write a Upgrade search using the UpgradeCode and ProductVersion range of the old product with the OnlyDetect attribute set to yes.  This will cause the property to have a value if the old product is detected. You can then use this property in a Condition element  (LaunchCondition).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me, but the other product (the old one) was installed per machine and the new MSI is per user. could this be related? Here's my code:   <SetProperty Id="OLDERFOUND" Before="LaunchConditions" Value="false">Not OLDERFOUND</SetProperty>
 <Upgrade Id='$(guid)'>
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='OLDERFOUND' Minimum='0.0.0' Maximum='7.2.0' IncludeMaximum='no' />  
 </Upgrade> 
 <Condition Message="Please remove the previous version before running this setup"><![CDATA[OLDERFOUND="false"]]></Condition>

Comment: Did you try it?  I know RemoveExistingProducts can only do like per-user/per-user or per-machine/per-machine but I'm pretty sure the FindRelatedProducts can detect per user or per machine installs because frequently the installation scope isn't even selected at this phase of the installation yet.

Comment: Did I try what? the code I posted in the comment? yes, but I thought maybe there's something wrong with it, that's why I shared it. I installed the 'old' MSI, then built the new MSI with the code I posted, and the MSI installed without displaying the error message. 
Current I have a working solution with a CA that uses ProductInstallation.GetRelatedProducts (C#) I just figured I best avoid CA as much as possible